# How to have a dynamic value using Redisearch ft.create?

Tags: redis, redisjson

I have a simple entry as such :

```
json.set a:1 . '{"name":"chloe", "age":26 , "foo" : {"bar" : 1}'
```

When creating an index I can go as far as

```
FT.CREATE ON JSON SCHEMA $.name AS name TEXT .....
```

However `bar` is a dynamic value and it can be changed. How can I create an index for a dynamic value under `foo`?

Comment: So are you thinking data that looks like this:

`{"name":"chloe", "age":26 , "foo" : {"bar" : 1}`
`{"name":"chloe", "age":26 , "foo" : {"baz" : 1}`
`{"name":"chloe", "age":26 , "foo" : {"qux" : 1}`

And you want to get the value of `1` regardless of the property name?

Comment: @GuyRoyse I wish to get the value of bar but bar is a variable and can be something else. I don't want to specify bar and wish to say any key that is the child of foo.

Comment: @GuyRoyse, I have a similar situation as you described in the comment, can you propose a solution and we can assume that `bar, baz, qux` are on the top level.

Comment: @JB's I think that is my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use full JSONPath syntax to match fields in the JSON. If the property `foo` will always contain an object *and* that object will always contain *one and only one* property, you could use a JSONPath `$.foo.*` like this:

```bash
> FT.CREATE a:index ON JSON SCHEMA $.name AS name TEXT $.foo.* AS num NUMERIC
OK
> FT.SEARCH a:index "@num:[1 1]"
1) (integer) 1
2) "a:1"
3) 1) "$"
   2) "{\"name\":\"chloe\",\"age\":26,\"foo\":{\"bar\":1}}"
```

Note that this JSONPath could very well return multiple results if `foo` contains more than one property:

```json
{
  "name" : "chloe",
  "age": 26,
  "foo": {
    "bar": 1,
    "baz": 13
  }
}
```

This could be desirable if your field is a TAG field and the JSON contained strings instead of numbers. But it won't work for a NUMERIC field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a JSONPath such as `$.foo.*`, which would match all immediate children of top-level `foo`.

If there are multiple children, support for multi values will be available with RediSearch 2.6.1.

If children are of different types, you can try using a filter to avoid indexing failures due to type mismatch, for example, `'$.foo.[?(@.*>-999)]'`, to handle specific numeric values, or `'$.foo.[?(@.*!="")]'` to handle text values.